# React TypeScript: Cannot get map() inside other map() in render() to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spfx, map-function

I want to render out messages and their replies in React (with TypeScript).

Messages are stored inside an array in the state and replies are stored inside a different array inside the state.

This is my current code, which results in not rendering out the message blocks:

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISpfxConversationsProps> {

    const { channelTopics, topicReplies, errorMessage } = this.state;

    const hideTitleContainer = this.props.isEditMode || this.props.title ? '' : styles.hidden;
    const wpTitleClasses = `${styles.webpartHeader} ${hideTitleContainer}`;

    return (
      <div className={ styles.spfxTecanTeamsConversations }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ wpTitleClasses }>
            { this.props.isEditMode && <textarea onChange={this.setTitle.bind(this)} className={styles["edit"]} placeholder={strings.WebpartTitlePlaceholder} aria-label={strings.WebpartTitlePlaceholder} defaultValue={this.props.title}></textarea> }
            { !this.props.isEditMode && <span className={styles["view"]}>{this.props.title}</span> }
          </div>
          { errorMessage ? <p className={ styles.textError }>{errorMessage}</p> : null }
          <div className={ styles.conversationsArea }>
            {
              channelTopics.map((topic: IChannelTopic, indexTopic) => {
                return (
                  this.renderMessageBlock( topic.message, indexTopic),
                  topicReplies.filter(r => r.topicMessageId === topic.id).map((reply: ITopicReply, indexReply) => {
                    return (
                      this.renderMessageBlock(reply.message, indexReply, true)
                    )
                  })
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  public renderMessageBlock(message: IChannelMessage, index: Number, isReply: boolean = false) {
    const replyStyle = isReply? '' : styles.messageReply;
    const messageBlockClasses = `${styles.messageBlock} ${replyStyle}`;
    return (
      <div className={ messageBlockClasses} key={`teams-message-${message.id}-${index}`}>
        <div className={ styles.messageHeader}>
          <span className={ styles.messageAuthor }>
            { message.fromUserDisplayName ? message.fromUserDisplayName : strings.UnknownAccount }
          </span>
          <span className={ styles.messageDate }>
          { this.renderDate(message.createdDateTime) }
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className={ styles.messageBody }>
          { message.deletedDateTime === null ? (message.contentType === 'html' ? renderHTML(message.content) : message.content) : this.renderDate(message.deletedDateTime) }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  public renderDate(date: Date) {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.inlineBlock }>
        <Moment format="d.M.yyyy">{date}</Moment> <Moment format="HH:mm:ss">{date}</Moment>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When I remove the 2nd `.map()` block + the comma right before, this one:

```
                        ,
              topicReplies.filter(r => r.topicMessageId === topic.id).map((reply: ITopicReply, indexReply) => {
                return (
                  this.renderMessageBlock(reply.message, indexReply, true)
                )
              })
```

I get the first level messages, but I cannot get both to work. I haven't found yet a good example how this must be structured so that it works.

What do I need to change?

Comment: You are returning in the form `(a,b)`. The comma operator ignores the first parameter, so this effectively returns `b`.Probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div className={styles.conversationsArea}>
  {/* The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand **/
   channelTopics.map((topic: IChannelTopic, indexTopic) => {
    return [
      this.renderMessageBlock(topic.message, indexTopic),
      topicReplies
        .filter((r) => r.topicMessageId === topic.id)
        .map((reply: ITopicReply, indexReply) => {
          return this.renderMessageBlock(reply.message, indexReply, true);
        })
    ]
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet for me, it works when I don't return the topicReplies...map() stuff in the first return but simply "<div>test</div>", I have to check if there is another issue (btw, I believe you forgot a '{' right after the comment).

Comment: There is no error in console or HTML, but I tested it and with your code the first call "this.renderMessageBlock(topic.message, indexTopic);" does not return anything, I believe because it gets overwritten with the return (..) value that follows.

Comment: `topicReplies.filter(r => r.topicMessageId === topic.id)` is there possible return an empty array?

Comment: I update my answer. if u want to return two components, you can return an array

Comment: yeah, I got it now working with your help. Looks like I had two errors, the issue that return() with comma returned something not useful and also I noticed that my secondary array was empty.